# Ionic : ngIf statement inside a ngFor not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I want to display data from database with the help of ngfor. I want to use ngif for implement some display condition .

my code :

```
<ion-grid  *ngFor="let chat of ChatListArray">
  <ion-row *ngIf="chat.status == 'Incoming'">
    <ion-col >
      <div>
       {{chat.msg}}
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <br>
  <ion-row *ngIf="chat.status == 'Outgoing'"> 
    <ion-col >
      <div>
       {{chat.msg }}
      </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

But its not working . how to use if statement properly please help.

{{chat.msg }} does not display any data.
but outside the ngif its works.

My json array :

[image]

Comment: Can you **[fork this Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yxesua)** and try to replicate your issue?

Comment: how your `ChatListArray` looks like?

Comment: @SiddAjmera not working in my case

Comment: Your JSON looks weird. It should be an array of objects (= your chat) but it is ... not really a array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok and it should work. It looks like you have typo into `ChatListArray` or `Incomming`. Maybe `Incoming`?

What you can do is to use `json` pipe to see values of `chat.status` to understand what values you are iterating:

```
<ion-grid  *ngFor="let chat of ChatListArray">
    <div>
       {{chat | json }}
    </div>
</ion-grid>
```

Your array contains just one object messages, so this is a reason why you cannot see any messages. E.g. `ngIf=chat.status == 'Incoming'`, it works and it will get this object `{"status":"Outgoing"}`, but this object does not have any `msg` object, because this object `msg` is the next in an iteration:

```
[
{"id":1},
{"number":"+..."},
{"status":"Outgoing"},
{"msg": "hello"},

{"id":2},
{"number":"+..."},
{"status":"Incoming"},
{"msg": "hello"},

{"id":3},
{"number":"+..."},
{"status":"Outgoing"},
{"msg": "hello"},
]
```

It will work, if you have such objects in your array:

```
[
{"id":1, "number":"+...", "status":"Outgoing", "msg": "hello"},

{"id":2, "number":"+...", "status":"Incoming", "msg": "hello"},

{"id":3, "number":"+...", "status":"Outgoing", "msg": "hello"}
]
```

Comment: {{chat.msg }} display value only outside the ngif statement

Comment: share your {{chat}} object